# How to create react-native apk in Expo?

Tags: react-native, expo

I want to create APK file of my project app. I am working on this [expo documentation](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/distribution/building-standalone-apps/) 
But it failed everytime what is wrong with this[image].

it gives this error cannot able to make a build.

```
 Copying resources from program jar [/app/turtle/workingdir/android/sdk35/android-shell-app/app/build/intermediates/transforms/mergeJavaRes/release/0.jar] (filtered)
/app/turtle/workingdir/android/sdk35/android-shell-app/app/build/intermediates/transforms/proguard/release/0.jar: D8: Type `libcore.io.Memory` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `void com.google.android.gms.internal.e.ej$a.a(long, byte)`
/app/turtle/workingdir/android/sdk35/android-shell-app/app/build/intermediates/transforms/proguard/release/0.jar: D8: Type `libcore.io.Memory` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `void com.google.android.gms.internal.o.gu$a.a(long, byte)`
> Task :app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForRelease
/app/turtle/workingdir/android/sdk35/android-shell-app/app/build/intermediates/transforms/proguard/release/0.jar: D8: Type `libcore.io.Memory` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `void com.google.android.gms.internal.q.gc$a.a(long, byte)`
/app/turtle/workingdir/android/sdk35/android-shell-app/app/build/intermediates/transforms/proguard/release/0.jar: D8: Type `org.conscrypt.Conscrypt` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `java.security.Provider okhttp3.internal.platform.ConscryptPlatform.getProvider()`
/app/turtle/workingdir/android/sdk35/android-shell-app/app/build/intermediates/transforms/proguard/release/0.jar: D8: Type `io.branch.referral.Branch` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `void host.exp.exponent.b.a.a(android.app.Application)`
/app/turtle/workingdir/android/sdk35/android-shell-app/app/build/intermediates/transforms/proguard/release/0.jar: D8: Type `org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `void org.b.c.c()`
/app/turtle/workingdir/android/sdk35/android-shell-app/app/build/intermediates/transforms/proguard/release/0.jar: D8: Type `libcore.io.Memory` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `void com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.cnv$b.a(long, byte)`
> Task :app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForRelease
> Task :app:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
> Task :app:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease
> Task :app:packageRelease FAILED
1605 actionable tasks: 1605 executed
[stderr] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[stderr] * What went wrong:
[stderr] Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.
[stderr] > com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key Techie@123 from store "/tmp/turtle/keystore-61d7d6e3-26f6-4954-b4a3-97305b4bfd3a.jks": No key with alias 'Techie@123' found in keystore /tmp/turtle/keystore-61d7d6e3-26f6-4954-b4a3-97305b4bfd3a.jks
[stderr] * Try:
[stderr] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
[stderr] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[stderr] BUILD FAILED in 6m 44s
Error: ./gradlew exited with non-zero code: 1
    at ChildProcess.completionListener (/app/turtle/node_modules/@expo/xdl/node_modules/@expo/spawn-async/build/spawnAsync.js:52:23)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:317:30)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:915:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
    ...
    at spawnAsync (/app/turtle/node_modules/@expo/xdl/node_modules/@expo/spawn-async/build/spawnAsync.js:17:21)
    at spawnAsyncThrowError (/app/turtle/node_modules/@expo/xdl/build/detach/ExponentTools.js:235:45)
    at buildShellAppAsync (/app/turtle/node_modules/@expo/xdl/build/detach/AndroidShellApp.js:881:11)
    at <anonymous>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a terminal/cmd prompt let the expo server running by `expo start` and in another terminal/cmd prompt run `expo build:android`
if did't work try to build by clearing the credentials run

> expo build:android -c

Comment: seems like there is a problem with your keystore pass key try again by clearing the credentials and keystore, run exp build:android -c and select let expo handle the keystore process

Comment: so it gives an error , hey can you help me , one more time ?

Comment: i updated the error in question  here is link to my build , https://expo.io/dashboard/anujswins/builds/61d7d6e3-26f6-4954-b4a3-97305b4bfd3a

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the `.expo` directory from the project root.

Comment: Build queued...connect ETIMEDOUT 104.197.216.164:443
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.197.216.164:443
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1107:14)

Comment: Your answer help , when i delete expo its start building but then it gives error

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure You have **package name** and **versioncode** inside the android like ( **android: {
   "package": "com.envogram.envogram",
   "versionCode": 1
   }**
   )  in "app.json" file.
2. Run **expo start**
3. Open another command prompt and run **expo build:android**.
4. Now wait for completing the bundle.
5. Check Status and queue of the app by generated link.
6. In the end Download the apk file and Install in mobile.

Answer (score -1):

> if you want to generate apk eject the CRNA with npm run eject command. Then you will get android and ios folders suppurate in mac
>    and you will get an only android folder in windows. and follow the instruction which is in a given link below
>
> ```
> "https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html"
> ```

Comment: Don't you read questions before answering what I am asking for?